# how to create sub rows in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I created a table using angular. Some rows in the table have child rows with the same properties as parent. I want to create the child rows whenever the user clicks on the parent row (parent rows would have a carrot sign that specifies there are some child rows). I am really new to angular and I need to see an example so that I can understand how it happens in angular. can anybody help?

here is my  html:

```
 <div data-ng-app="myModule">
     <div data-ng-controller="myController">
         <table>
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <tr data-ng-repeat="student in students">
                    <th>
                       <span data-ng-show="{{student.hasChildren}}">
                           <image data-ng-click="getChildren(student)" data-ng-src="image"></image>
                       </span>
                     </th>
                     <th>{{student.firstName}}</th>
                     <th>{{student.lastName}}</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr data-ng-repeat="child in children">
                     <th></th>
                     <th>{{child.firstName}}</th>
                     <th>{{child.lastName}}</th>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
  </div>
```

the "hasChildren" cell would have a carrot sign which will collapse and expand the children rows.

here is the js file:

```
var app = angular
.module("myModule", [])
.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: contextPath + '/students'
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            var students = response.data;
            $scope.students = students;
        });

    $scope.getChildren = function(student){
        var parentStudentId = student.id;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: contextPath + '/students/children?studentId=' + parentStudentId
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            var children = response.data;
            $scope.children = children;
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what the HTML should look like and a data structure? We can't help you with what you've given us.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I added the code to my original question. What I want is to get the children rows using another ajax call when the user clicks on the parent row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on that approach

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="parent in parents">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Parent ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="SomeCarrotCondition(parent)" ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
      <td>
        Child...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Code sample:

```
$scope.getChildren = function(student) {
    studen.expanded = !student.expanded; // expand/collapse items
    if (student.children) { // request a server only once to get the children
        return;
    }

    var parentStudentId = student.id;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: contextPath + '/students/children?studentId=' + parentStudentId
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        student.children = response.data; // fill student children collection
    });
}
```

HTML sample:

```
<div data-ng-app="myModule">
    <div data-ng-controller="myController">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-ng-repeat="student in students">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <span data-ng-show="{{student.hasChildren}}">
                        <image data-ng-click="getChildren(student)" data-ng-src="image"></image>
                    </span>
                </th>
                <th>{{student.firstName}}</th>
                <th>{{student.lastName}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="child in student.children" 
                ng-show="student.expanded">
                <th></th>
                <th>{{child.firstName}}</th>
                <th>{{child.lastName}}</th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added my code to the question. But the problem is when I click on the parent row it is adding the new row at the bottom of the table. I want to insert the child rows under the parent row. Do you know what should be the changes?

Comment: @Markov Sergey -- thanks for the sample. I asked another question which is similar to this one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579658/how-to-show-sub-rows-as-a-nested-table-in-angularjs-ng-repeat  can you please take look and see what is the problem in my code?